# Stop overscroll effect on ios when using a ScrollPanel

Tags: gwt

I have a `ScollPanel` which takes up the full width and height of the browser:

```
ScrollPanel p = new ScrollPanel();
p.setWidth(Window.getClientWidth() + "px");
p.setHeight(Window.getClientHeight() + "px");
```

On an ios6 device, scrolling seems clunky - I found this css style to fix that though:

```
// webkitOverflowScrolling
p.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("webkitOverflowScrolling", "touch");
```

which gives me that native scrolling feel, which is great.

Is there a way to prevent the "overscroll" effect? By that I mean, when I'm at scroll pos = 0, and I continue dragging down, the whole body appears to be scrolled even more, revealing empty space above the top of my page contents.

I've already disabled bouncing on the UIWebView itself that I'm running this page in:

```
[self.mWebView.scrollView setBounces:NO];
```

which worked perfectly when I was not using a `ScrollPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at mgwt: http://www.m-gwt.com

This is a library for writing mobile applications with GWT.

There is a scrollpanel in there optimized for mobile and a solution for preventing scrolling on the body.